# Find the Nth occurence of a specific value in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

In a table originally with the columns "ID" and "Scope", I would like to add another column "SkipOccurrence" that shows the Nth occurence of the Value "Skip" in column "Scope"

```
ID|Scope  |SkipOccurrence|minID|maxID
--|-------|--------------------------
1 |Include|              |     |
2 |Include|              |     |
3 |Skip   |1             |1    |2
4 |Include|              |     |
5 |Skip   |2             |4    |4
6 |Include|              |     |
7 |Include|              |     |
8 |Skip   |3             |6    |7
9 |Include|              |     |
```

In the end, I am looking for a way to work out the ID ranges of the rows having "Include" in the "Scope" column.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Why do you want to add this as a new column? You generally should not add derivable data to your table.

Comment: what are you using? t-sql, oracle, MySQL, postgres?

Comment: My downvote for not tagging specific database

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select
    id,
    scope,
    case when scope = 'Skip' then n end as skipoccurrence
from (
  select
      id,
      scope,
      row_number() over(partition by scope order by id) as n
    from my_table
) x
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking to update the table after adding the new column.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.SkipOccurrence = a.NextNumber
FROM (SELECT SkipOccurrence, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS NextNumber
      FROM myTable
      WHERE Scope = 'Skip') a
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, I wasn't very clear initially. In the end, I am looking for a way to work out the ID ranges of the rows having "Include" in the "Scope" column. In other words I need the output to give me four ranges: 1. min ID = 1, max ID = 2; 2. min ID = 4, max ID =4; 3.min ID=6, max ID =7; 4.min ID = 9, max ID = 9

Comment: Please update the question with that reflected in the sample result.